# How to write spring @ConfigurationProperties class to read map on second level?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml

In yaml I have such properties:

```
threadPools:
  poollA:
    size: 10
    maxSize: 20
 poolB:
    size: 20
```

How can I write @ConfigurationProperties class to map this config to have Map of pool configurations?

If there is one more level it's quite easy:

```
threadPools:
  configs:
    poollA:
      size: 10
      maxSize: 20
    poolB:
      size: 20
```

and java(kotlin, actually) class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("threadPools")
internal class ThreadPoolsProperties {

    val configs: Map<String, ThreadPoolConfig> = mutableMapOf()

    internal class ThreadPoolConfig {
        var size: Int = 10
        var maxSize: Int = 10
    }
}
```

But what with first example?